# WATIN giving "Dialog not available within n seconds" error

Tags: c#, mstest, coded-ui-tests, watin

I'm using WATIN with IE 10. The `alert` dialog box shows up, but WATIN doesn't seem to be able to find it.

```
var driver = new IE(true);
driver.GoTo("site-url");
driver.WaitForComplete();
var alert = new AlertDialogHandler();
using (new UseDialogOnce(driver.DialogWatcher, alert))
    {
        driver.Button("btnSearch").ClickNoWait();
        alert.WaitUntilExists(5); // <-- error here
        alert.OKButton.Click();
        driver.WaitForComplete();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help, I've had the same problem:

```
var driver = new IE(true);
driver.GoTo("site-url");
driver.WaitForComplete();
var alert = new AlertDialogHandler();
driver.AddDialogHandler(alert);
using (new UseDialogOnce(driver.DialogWatcher, alert))
    {
        driver.Button("btnSearch").ClickNoWait();
        alert.WaitUntilExists(5); // <-- error here
        alert.OKButton.Click();
        driver.WaitForComplete();
     }
```

The key is adding the `DialogHandler` to the `IE` instance.